# Basic C# lists - Adding an unknown number of items

Tags: c#

I am teaching myself C# and modern Windows programming in general and had a question about lists in C# that I haven't found an answer for.  The reference book I am using seems to indicate that in C# before you can assign a variable to a list, you need to define a new variable for each item in the list and assign it's value.

I am trying to write a simple program that will let me write text notes, assign keywords to them, and them filter the resulting group of notes based on the keywords I select.  From what I can figure out, a List seems the best mechanism in C# to do this since there will be an unknown number of notes.  However, I am struggling with the idea of defining a unknown number of variable names ahead of time to store the notes in, to add to the List.

Am I looking at the wrong construct in C# for this, misunderstanding what is required to assign a variable value to a List, or lacking knowledge of some mechanism for auto-creating variables and variable names that can be leveraged as part of a list?  Something else?

Sorry if this is too simple a question for SE crowd, but this seemed like the best place to ask.

Comment: Why would you need "unknown number of variable names"? If x is a list, each member can be accessed with x[0], x[1], etc. As for filtering keywords, you can handle them with Dictionary<string,List<int>> where the keys are keyword, the values point to the indexes of the note with that keyword. Or you can just went to DB route and have a Keyword table to handle it, in which case it's DB 101.

Comment: I think you read it wrong. you can definitely add any number of items into the list whenever you want

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. `List` is a collection of specific type of objects you can add/remove objects from the list, and can access it with its index. If you want to use a key value pair you can use `Dictionary`. If you want an object with dynamic property you may need to use [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `List<T>` is a data structure that lets you store an unknown number of `T`, but you don't need variable names for the elements of the list - just for the list itself.

Is this what you need?

```
var notes = new List<string>()
{
    "This is a note.",
    "I am happy",
};

notes.Add("This is another happy note");

notes.AddRange(new [] { "Another happy notes", "This is also a note", });

var selected = notes.Where(n => n.Contains("happy")).ToList();
```

The values in `selected` are:

> "I am happy", "This is another happy note", "Another happy notes"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly is your confusion. But it sounds like you are having issues in constructing class or using C# types. To keep it simple for now you can follow something in this manner.

```
// This represents individual note
public class Note 
{
    // Initialize keywords list in constructor
    // in order to avoid Null reference exception.
    public Note() {
        Keywords = new List<string>();
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<string> Keywords { get; set; }
}

// In main code, you can simply have List<Note> to hold collection of any no of notes.
// Also, when user adds a note you will create a new Note instance and add to collection.
List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();

Note newNote = new Note();
newNote.Title = "Note 1";
newNote.Content = "Note 1 Content";
newNote.Keywords.Add("Test1");

notes.Add(newNote);
```

Comment: This is an example of the confusion I had because you have the "notes.Add(newNote)" line, and other examples I had seen would call the next item to be added to the list with a different variable name (in this example maybe "newNote2").  So the way I interpreted it was that the only way to ever refer to that value in the List was by the original variable name (e.g. "newNote", "newNote1", etc.).  @Martheen above seems to be answering my question that you can use the variable name as a placeholder and then access any item in the list with a location such as x[1].  If correct, that answers my Q.